# How detect the device type programmatically whether tablet or mobile

Tags: android, tablet

I need to show different notification to the user if he/she is using tablet against that of mobile. So is there any way to detect whether the device is tablet or mobile.

Comment: You can look at the screen size and or the api version. Would recommend screen size as api 4.0 works for both phones and tablets.

Answer (score 2):

You can see below post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11330947/1441666

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

which will return true if the device is operating on a large screen.

Comment: This will not work if the device is a smartphone but has a large screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to how you get the screen densities: [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

You'll then do something like this if(screen > comparevalue) then we have tablet, else phone.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to detect is to detect the Android version 
Check the variable android.os.Build.VERSION, honeycomb devices are tablets 2.x devices are phones or tablets.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: Yes but this will be flawed in the long run as 4.0 works for tablets as well. Screen size would be the right way to go :)

Comment: Phones now run 4.0+ as well as tablets.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected String getDeviceType() {
boolean status = (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
if (status)
        return "Mobile";
    else
        return "Tablet";
}
```